# Server sent event messaging issue

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I was looking for a way to get feedback on the progress of a long running script and came across server-sent events.  I followed the guidelines set down here http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/receive-updates-from-the-server-using-the-eventsource.html , copied the examples given, created a couple of php files and put them on my localhost server on my laptop (running Apache web server).

They worked just fine, the server returned a message each second of the message loop which I received in the browser. I tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE and of course IE just reported the "not supported" message as expected.

Before diving in to create my real application I then copied the two files up to my production company server (running IIS) and called them from the same browser on my laptop.

The result was that I got all the messages, but only AFTER the loop had completed, not at the time each iteration message was sent, which of course rather defeats the object.

Am I missing something - might there be some setting on the IIS server restricting use of sse? If so what?

Any help appreciated.

Here are the two files (apart from a name change they follow pretty exactly the examples on more than one introductory web page on the subject):

First file ssetest.php:

```
<?php

    echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /></head><body>";

    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

    var esSupport = false, es, result;

    function init() {
      noEsSupport = (window.EventSource === undefined);
      if(noEsSupport) addLog('This browser does not support server-sent events.<br>You will not get any progress messages.<br>Try Firefox or Chrome');
    }

    window.onload = init;

    function startTask() {
        es = new EventSource('ssetest_task.php');

        //a message is received
        es.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            var result = JSON.parse( e.data );

            addLog(result.message);       

            if(e.lastEventId == 'CLOSE') {
                addLog('Received CLOSE closing');
                es.close();
                var pBar = document.getElementById('progressor');
                pBar.value = pBar.max; //max out the progress bar
            }
            else {
                var pBar = document.getElementById('progressor');
                pBar.value = result.progress;
                var perc = document.getElementById('percentage');
                perc.innerHTML   = result.progress  + \"%\";
                perc.style.width = (Math.floor(pBar.clientWidth * (result.progress/100)) + 15) + 'px';
            }
        });

        es.addEventListener('error', function(e){addLog('Error occurred'); es.close();});
    }

    function stopTask() {
        es.close();
        addLog('Interrupted');
    }

    function addLog(message) {
        var r = document.getElementById('results');
        r.innerHTML += message + '<br>';
        r.scrollTop = r.scrollHeight;
    }
    </script>";

    echo "<br />";
    echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"startTask();\"  value=\"Start Long Task\" />";
    echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"stopTask();\"  value=\"Stop Task\" />";
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo "<p>Results</p>";
    echo "<br /><div id=\"results\" style=\"border:1px solid #000; padding:10px; width:300px; height:250px; overflow:auto; background:#eee;\"></div><br />";
    echo "<progress id='progressor' value='0' max='100'></progress> "; 
    echo "<span id=\"percentage\" style=\"text-align:right; display:block; margin-top:5px;\">0</span>";
    echo "</body></html>";

?>
```

and the task file ssetest_task.php:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    // recommended to prevent caching of event data.
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

    function send_message($id, $message, $progress) {
        $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress);      
        echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "data: " . json_encode($d) . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;      
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

    //LONG RUNNING TASK
    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        send_message($i, 'on iteration ' . $i . ' of 10' , $i*10); 
        sleep(1);
    }

    send_message('CLOSE', 'Process complete');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've overcome these issues on IIS with the web.config settings that follow. The important bit is setting PHP's `responseBufferLimit=0`. You'll have to adjust for the version of PHP on your server

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP55_via_FastCGI" />
            <add name="PHP55_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        </handlers>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```